# drawing a dashed area using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Good morning,
I'm trying to reproduce the following pictures to be inserted in my course:

[image]

[image]

But I don't have any idea how to obtain the dashed area. Here is my code of the axis:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[holdot/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=1.5pt}]
        \draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-4,-3) grid (4,3);
        \draw[->,ultra thick] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
        \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};
        
        \draw[thick,red,domain=-1.42:1.42,samples=200] (0.5,2) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathcal{C}_{f}$} plot(\x,{\x^3});
        \draw [-, green,thick] (2,0) -- (2,3);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, extend your code snippet to complete, but minimal document, which we can test as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your pictures don't correspond to the output of your LaTeX document, let's stay general: a plot can be part of a bigger path and hence it's possible to define a closed path under a curve:

```
\draw[fill=orange] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:1.2] (\x, {\x^3}) -- (1.2,0) -- cycle;
```

will paint orange the area under the curve, over the interval [1, 1.2].
[image: output]

Comment: @Christopf Fing thank you very much, this is what I need. I don’t know know why some person voted -1 for my question.